# Как сократить код не используя цикл for

Tags: c#

Есть массив ключ=значение `string`, значение имеет разделители `, |` после `.Split` остаются начальные пробелы. Убрать нужно только начальные пробелы, собственно как сократить этот код ?
P/s метод рабочий, интересует только сокращение.

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();

foreach (var p in data)
{
    var d = p.Values.Split(new char[] { ',', '|'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    for (int i = 0; i < d.Length; i++)
    {
        d[i] = d[i].TrimStart();
    }
    dict.Add(p.Name, d);
}
```

Comment: Что делает этот код? что хранится в data?

Comment: пока вижу 2 варианта - select из Linq, и split по регулярному выражению, тогда не нужно будет делать TrimStart

Comment: Не хотел бы использовать `RegexSplit`

Comment: Он позволит сразу получить необходимый массив без необходимости внутреннего `for`

Comment: @Grundy спасибо, что-то переработался ступор, оформите как ответ приму.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var dict = data.ToDictionary(
    k => k.Name,
    p => p.Values.Split(new char[] { ',', '|'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                 .Select(v => v.TrimStart())
                 .ToArray());
```

Может где скобки потерял.